# Scrapy parsing different detail page from listings

Tags: python, html, css, scrapy

I am scraping a website's detail pages from a listing page, with some differences in each detail page.

1st detail page:

```
<div class="td-post-content">
    <p style="text-align: justify;">
        <strong>[ Karda Natam ]</strong>
        <br>
        <strong>ITANAGAR, May 6:</strong> Nacho, Taksing, Siyum and ...
        <br> “Offices are without ...
    </p>
</div>
```

2nd detail page:

```
<div class="td-post-content">
    <p style="text-align: justify;">
        <strong>Guwahati, May 6 (PTI)</strong> Sarbananda Sonowal today ...
        <br> “Books are a potent tool to create ...
    </p>
</div>
```

3rd detail page:

```
<div class="td-post-content">
    <h3 style="text-align: justify;"><strong>Flights Of Fantasy</strong></h3>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">
        <strong>[ M Panging ]</strong>
        <br> This state of denial ...
    </p>
</div>
```

I am trying to parse the author and post date from the detail page:

```
class ArunachaltimesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    ...
    ...

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.css("div.td-ss-main-content > div.td_module_16 > div.item-details > h3.entry-title > a::attr(href)").extract()
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_detail)

        next = response.xpath("// ...')]/@href").extract_first()
        if next:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_detail(self, response):
        strong_elements = response.css("div.td-ss-main-content").css("div.td-post-content").css("p > strong::text").extract()
        for strong in strong_elements:
            if ', ' in strong:
                news_date = strong.split(', ')[1].replace(":", "")
            elif '[ ' and ' ]' in strong:
                author = strong
            else:
                news_date = None
                author = None
        yield {
            'author': author,
            'news_date': news_date
        }
```

But I am getting this error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'author' referenced before assignment

What am I doing wrong here? Could you please how to get the author and news date from each page respectively. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

looks like `strong_elements` is empty array in your case. so `for` loop dont run. But you declared `author` variable in for loop, and you are using `author` in yield which is not declared (becoz `for` loop not running) in your case. declare `author` variable in top level like above `for` loop